# Create geometric series of points along line in ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, shapefile

I have a line shapefile and I want to create geometric series of points along that line. First point will be on 1 meter from start point, second point on 2 meters from start point, third point on 4  meters from start point, fourth point on 8 meters, next one from 16 meters, next one 32 meters and continue up to the end point of line. I guess that there is no existing tool in ArcGIS that can do this so there must be written the script.

Comment: This seems simple enough to do in ArcPy. You can even use code samples from arcpy.da.SearchCursor an arcpy.da.InsertCursor documentation to put together 80-85% of the code needed.